# Default user agent ProductName/Version CFNetwork/Darwin appears in proxy

Tags: ios

I am loading a url request in uiwebview. I have connected my iPad to Charles proxy. When the webview loads this request i see two same requests being shown in the proxy and it shows the below user agents for each request.

1. [Product Name/Version]/CFNetwork/Darwin/...
2. Mozilla/5.0 iPad..............

Now, I don't want to see the first user agent in the proxy since it contains 'Product Name' of my app.

I tried all possible things. I tried setting the default user agent to the NSMutableRequest. I also tried setting the user agent to register defaults. Nothing worked so far.

Registering defaults:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kAddonUserAgent],@"UserAgent",nil]; 
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];
```

kAddonUserAgent here is the Mozilla/5.0 user agent

Modifying the request:

```
[request setValue:@"Mozilla/5.0 iPad......." forhttpHeaderfield:@"User-Agent"];
```

I believe, CFNetwork is an iOS framework which is called internally and it cannot be avoided from being shown in proxy. Or is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please show your attempts for setting the default user agent.

Comment: Firstly, i need to know whether this is possible at all.

Comment: NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kAddonUserAgent],@"UserAgent",nil];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];

Comment: kAddonUserAgent here is the Mozilla/5.0 user agent

Comment: [request setValue:@"Mozilla/5.0 iPad......." forhttpHeaderfield:@"User-Agent"]. Even this does not work

Comment: I just don't want to see CFNetwork/Darwin user agent in my proxy. Is this something that's being set internally?

Comment: It _is_ possible, and it works pretty much like in your comment. When are you registering these defaults, and are you sure that code is right? it doesn't make sense to get a user agent from user defaults _before_ you register defaults.

Comment: that user agent kAddonUseragent comes from an API as response.That's not an issue here. The issue is mainly with seeing CFNetwork user agent string in the proxy server

Comment: How do i see the user agent CFNetwork/Darwin in the proxy when i have not set this anywhere? Is this some default user agent being set internally?

Comment: Yes, it's the default user agent for UIWebView. I think your problem is that you are not setting these defaults early enough in your app. If it comes from an API, by definition it's too late.

Comment: I am setting this in applicationdidFinishLaunching.

Comment: The problem is with the request being calling twice, out of which one request happens internally when a url is called which sets the user agent to ProductName/Version/CFNetwork/Darwin/..

Comment: I don't want to see this user agent in the proxy. Is there a way here to avoid this from seeing in proxy?

Comment: The second request will be shown with the correct user agent that i set. But i am just wondering what is that first request? Webview is loaded with the request just once.